# Category blog on homepage: how to open detail article as part of a different menu item?

Tags: menu, category-blog

Following scenario:

i published 2 separate main menu items: "Home" & "News"

- for "**home**": i got a category blog published as homepage menu item showing the latest 3 articles tagged as category "news", and some other modules around it
- for "**news**" this is also a category blog but with a list of all news intros without any other modules
- in general the news are published as intro & detail article, thus showing on the homepage only an intro image and intro text

The issue is now, that when a website visitor clicks the homepage news teaser, then the detail news opens and in the menu the "**home**" remains active. But I'd want that the menu item is "**news**".

The same issue applies if a detail news article is opened from the category blog in "**news**", then unfortunately also "**home**" is set active.

Is there any workaround for this scenario? So that I can control that always a specific main menu item is active if the detail page of a category blog is opened?

I'm already using the Advanced Module Manager joomla extensions, but this only helps to hide / control modules aroud a categeory blog, but does not help to modify behavior of the category blog detail page mechanism or URL handling.

Thank you for your help.
Andre

Comment: Can't tell from this if there is a menu item for the news detail page. Is there more than one? Less?

Answer (score 0):

I can see your problem - and did not notice this behaviour before.

I don't know an easy setup change - but i can think of a 'quick and dirty' solution using a system plugin, set the active menu in the 'OnBeforeRender' function using the note field of the article...
 like this:

```
public function OnBeforeRender() {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $article_id=$app->input->get('id');
    $article =JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    $note = $article->get('note');
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
    $menu->setActive($note);
}
```

HTH - Martin - write me if you need more help with the plugin

Comment: A more friendly approach would be to simply create a custom field for the article and use that. That way the field even has a label and tooltip that will properly explain what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module to present article intros from a category on the home page, and publish the articles in blog view as a component on the News page. Cliking the read-more link from the home page located article intro will lead youy to the complete article on your News page in this set-up.

There are loads of more specialised modules you can find on the [Joomla Extension Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org/) that give you all sorts of possibilities as to ways of presentation for this.